# SplashScreen Freezed doesn't take me to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Greeting
I created a splashscreen at my app and when i test it it get freeze and the app doesn't take me to the another activity i also made a timer '3 seconds' then it's should take me to the main activity but it's appear then freeze

```
public class Activity_SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent;
    View mDecorView;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        hideSystemUI();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    intent = new Intent(Activity_SplashScreen.this,Activity_SplashScreen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
        // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are starting an intent to the same class. Provide the class of the activity to which you want to navigate to. You are going from splash screen to splashscreen.